# How to align braces RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I'd like to make this the default:

```r
foo <- function(x)
{
    return(x)
}
```

The default is currently:

```r
foo <- function(x) {
    return(x)
}
```

When I hit enter before the opening brace RStudio does:

```r
foo <- function(x)
    {
    return(x)
}
```

Comment: I don't think that there is any direct way to do that, but it is easy enough to write code in RStudio using the indentation style that you prefer.

Comment: Both are incorrect. You need parenthesis around x in your return statement of you're going to use return. :D

Comment: @Dason or you can remove `return`

Comment: I know I know. And I know it's a touch faster but that is one place I disagree with the style guide on.

Comment: @Dason Edited lol.

Comment: @JohnColeman when you press enter it indents the brace (see edited question).

Comment: After typing `foo <- function(x)\n` type a backspace before typing `{`. You can regard the auto-indent as a suggestion which you are welcome to override.

Comment: It's odd that it would indent even without a brace no? Can you disable auto-indent?

Comment: Why do you find it odd? In the context of a function definition, it is expecting the body of the function to follow, which it indents. As far as turning it off goes, if it is anywhere it would be under `Tools > Global Options > Code`, but doesn't seem to be there. You can experiment, but it only takes a half of a second to hit the backspace key, so it isn't really something that would save you much time if you turn it off. Maybe you could ask on the [RStudio forum](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-ide-discussion/34).

Comment: It's odd that it doesn't depend on an opening brace to determine the next input as a function body. Most sophisticated editors like emacs do. Reducing repeated key strokes saves time. Thanks for the link, might be worth a shot.